Specifying all continuous r.v. independent with given continuous r.v.
I become curious about the question, for given continuous r.v, can we specify all continuous r.v. independent with previous one. To be precise,
Let $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), Leb)$ be probability space, and let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable space. Let $X:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous r.v(give $[0,1]$ subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$). Now can we specify all possible continuous r.v. $Y:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ independent with $X$?
For example, if $X(x) = x$, $Y$ can only be trivial constant function. Choose some $x \in (0,1), \epsilon>0, \delta>0$ so that $Y^{-1}((Y(x)-\epsilon, Y(x)+\epsilon))\supset(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ using continuity. Since $X^{-1}(x-\delta,x+\delta) = (x-\delta,x+\delta)$, $2\delta = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap Y^{-1}((Y(x)-\epsilon, Y(x)+\epsilon)) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x-\delta,x+\delta))\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}((Y(x)-\epsilon, Y(x)+\epsilon) = 2\delta\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}((Y(x)-\epsilon, Y(x)+\epsilon)$, thus $\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}((Y(x)-\epsilon, Y(x)+\epsilon) = 1$
This holds for any $x$ and $\epsilon$, so with some extra argument using continuity, $Y$ must be constant function.
Such approach cannot be directly applied to other $X$, which includes even continuous but not monotone in any interval. I know we may use joint pdf law $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ by substituting things about $X$ in there, but what should be done next? How to handle that $f_{X, Y}$ part? It feels like solving some strange variant of differential equations, and i have no idea how.
